# object shape change when i duplicate object in a curve

Tags: modifiers

How can I duplicate object without shape change, or another good way to duplicate an object in a circle?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using dupliverts instead of the array modifier. The [manual page on Dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html?highlight=dupliverts) explains it well:

> First, in Object Mode, select the base object and Shift-RMB to add the
>   circle to the selection (order is very important here), and Ctrl-P to
>   parent the base object to the circle. Now, the circle is the parent of
>   the monkey; if you move the circle, the monkey will follow it.
>
> With only the circle selected, enable Duplication vertices in the
>   Object panel ‣ Duplication ‣ Vertices. A monkey head should be placed
>   at every vertex of the circle.

[image]

Be sure to go to the bottom left of the manual page and use the pop-up menu to switch from English to your language, if it is on the list.